# How can I divide two integers to get a double?

Tags: c#, math, int, double

How do I divide two integers to get a double?

Comment: Assuming this was asked in an interview - integer division always results in integer. You must use a type cast like the ones shown below.

Comment: Different types of divisions: Integer ,Floating-point ,Decimal -discussed in [Why integer division in c# returns an integer but not a float?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10851273)

Answer (score 576, accepted):

You want to cast the numbers:

```
double num3 = (double)num1/(double)num2;
```

Note: If any of the arguments in C# is a `double`, a `double` divide is used which results in a `double`. So, the following would work too:

```
double num3 = (double)num1/num2;
```

For more information see:

[Dot Net Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/numeric-casts)

Comment: Don't know if this is the same in C#, but C only requires you to cast the first - it'll automatically make double/int a double.

Comment: @Pax, If any of the args in C or C# are a double, a double divide is used (resulting in a double).

Comment: Be careful not to do this:- `double num3 = (double)(num1/num2);`. This will just give you a double representation of the result of the integer division!

Comment: Supposing you don't need the extra precision, is there a reason to cast to `double` instead of `float`? I can see the question calls for `double` but I'm curious anyway.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Just cause in C# we normally use `double` and not `float`. When you write a variable just like `var a = 1.0;`, this 1.0 is always a `double`. I guess this is the main reason.

Comment: Yes, in VB 1/2 is 1.  (FML right?)  Cdec(1) / Cdec(2) = 0.5

Answer (score 49):

Complementing the @NoahD's answer

To have a greater precision you can cast to decimal:

```
(decimal)100/863
//0.1158748551564310544611819235
```

Or:

```
Decimal.Divide(100, 863)
//0.1158748551564310544611819235
```

Double are represented allocating 64 bits while decimal uses 128

```
(double)100/863
//0.11587485515643106
```

#### In depth explanation of "precision"

For more details about the floating point representation in binary and its precision take a look at [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) from Jon Skeet where he talks about `floats` and `doubles` and [this one](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) where he talks about `decimals`.

Comment: Wrong! `double` has a precision of 53 bits, and it's a **binary** floating-point format, whereas `decimal` is a... decimal one, of course, with [96 bits of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801440/995714). So `double` is precise to ~15-17 decimal digits and decimal 28-29 digits (and not twice the precision of `double`). More importantly `decimal` actually uses only 102 of the 128 bits

Comment: Thanks @phuclv, fixed that. I meant "space allocation". You were right about the precision of `decimals` (96), but `doubles` has [52 bits of mantissa](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx), not 53.

Comment: yes, the mantissa has 52 bits, but there's still a hidden bit, resulting in a 53-bit significand. [Is it 52 or 53 bits of floating point precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18409496/995714)

Comment: Decimal.Divide was great! Thx

Answer (score 10):

cast the integers to doubles.

Comment: To be specific, you can cast an integer to a double like so:  (double)myIntegerValue

Answer (score 9):

Convert one of them to a double first.  This form works in many languages:

```
 real_result = (int_numerator + 0.0) / int_denominator
```

Comment: Easier to just do... `var result = 1.0 * a / b;`

Comment: @Basic there's 100 ways to do it. I prefer addition just because it's faster, although casting is obviously faster still.

Answer (score 4):

```
var firstNumber=5000,
secondeNumber=37;

var decimalResult = decimal.Divide(firstNumber,secondeNumber);

Console.WriteLine(decimalResult );
```

Comment: The question seems to call for `double` and not `decimal`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = decimal.ToDouble(decimal.Divide(5, 2));
```

Comment: 5 = first number, 2 = second number

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add information. Please don't add it in comments

Answer (score 1):

In the [comment to the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double/75405878?noredirect=1#comment41232512_661042) there is a distinction made which seems to be worth highlighting in a separate answer.

The correct code:

```
double num3 = (double)num1/(double)num2;
```

is not the same as casting the result of integer division:

```
double num3 = (double)(num1/num2);
```

Given num1 = 7 and num2 = 12:

The correct code will result in num3 = 0.5833333

Casting the result of integer division will result in num3 = 0.00

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Added link to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have went through most of the answers and im pretty sure that it's unachievable. Whatever you try to divide two int into double or float is not gonna happen.
But you have tons of methods to make the calculation happen, just cast them into float or double before the calculation will be fine.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Please make sure to include new information (that is not in the other answers) in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is adding decimal places to your integer.

Ex.:

```
var v1 = 1 / 30 //the result is 0
var v2 = 1.00 / 30.00 //the result is 0.033333333333333333
```