# How do you divide integers and get a double in C#?

Tags: c#, math

```
int x = 73;  
int y = 100;  
double pct = x/y;
```

Why do I see 0 instead of .73?

Comment: Not only C#, but a batch of other languages including C and C++.  Common Lisp will return 73/100, and languages like Perl that lack an actual integer type will return 0.73.

Comment: How does one gain over 6K rep and not already know the answer to this question?

Comment: @SouceMaster: Because rep (a) doesn't measure ability, it measures participation, and (b) because OO simply asks bazillions of questions (10x as many as answers provided).  There is a discussion on this on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: a junior member of my team asked this after googling for a little while.  I suggested that it be posted on SOF for a quicker and more accurate solution.  i was correct.  Now when he googles this, this post comes up first (and thus SOF is making googling better)

Comment: Maybe the junior members of your team should have SOF accounts.

Comment: @oo: couldn't have just told him the answer? :p

Comment: but if i just told him, the folks that google this in the future dont get this page as a solution at the top of their list . . . saving time for future programmers everywhere . .

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double

Comment: @oo: Is that story true, or are you just rep-whoring?

Comment: @oo: your story is too fake to believe. "Qucker & More Accurate"?? wth!! its just a simple and a single answer. Tell me how could you make answer to this "More Accurate" or "Less Accurate".

Comment: faster then . . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741083/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions-on-stack-overflow-closed

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because the division is done with integers then converted to a double.  Try this instead:

```
double pct = (double)x / (double)y;
```

Comment: Just for completeness: Converting one of the ints to double is enough, but it doesn't hurt to convert them both :)

Answer (score 8):

It does the same in all C-like languages.  If you divide two integers, the result is an integer.  0.73 is not an integer.

The common work-around is to multiply one of the two numbers by 1.0 to make it a floating point type, or just cast it.

Answer (score 3):

because the operation is still on int type. Try `double pct = (double)x / (double)y;`

Answer (score 2):

Integer division drops the fractional portion of the result. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the flow of execution in a line of code.  You're correct to assume that setting the right side of the equation equal to `double` (on the left side) will implicitly convert the solution as a double.  However, the flow execution dicates that x/y is evaluated *by itself* before you even get to the `double pct =` portion of the code.  Thus, since two `int`s are divided by each other, they will evaluate to an `int` solution (in this case, rounding towards zero) *before* being implicitly converted to a double.

As other have noted, you'll need to cast the `int` variables as `double`s so the solution comes out as a `double` and not as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

That’s because the type of the left hand operand of the division (`x`) is of type `int`, so the return type of `x / y` is still `int`. The fact that the destination variable is of type `double` doesn’t affect the operation.
To get the intended result, you first have to cast (convert) `x` to `double`, as in:

```
double pct = (double)x / y;
```

Comment: Which operand is double doesn't matter.  `Either (double)73/100` or `73/(double)100` would work just fine.  If one operand is a double, all integer types will be coerced to double.