# Looping through all representable decimals in ascending order

Tags: c#, floating-point

If I take the lower 31 bits of a `float` (exponent and mantissa) and loop through them one by one, the resulting floats are in ascending order starting from `0`, up to `float.MaxValue`, then to `float.PositiveInfinity` and then further on to the many different bit patterns of `float.NaN`.

This nice property doesn't seem to hold for the `decimal` data type. Is there a way to loop through all representable decimal values (between a lower and an upper bound) in ascending order in a similar way?

Bonus: Is there at quick way to count the possible numbers?

Additional information: It's okay to count 1.0 and 1.00 as two different numbers.

Comment: Have you read The Jon's answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801440/binary-representation-of-a-net-decimal Perhaps it can shed some light. As far as I can understand, it might not be possible, since there are multiple representations for the same number.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea: Iterating through all representable values is of course possible. One would skip non-canonical representations (for any desired assignment of canonical).

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah.... good point. It might be time to go sleep. Brain slow. Cannot edit my comment this late, and I still think that that post might be useful

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea: I've read the article, I know how the `decimal` data type looks in memory. Still I haven't found a good way to enumerate or count the representable decimals between two given decimals min and max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decimal` format has a sign bit *s*, a 96-bit significand *f*, and an exponent *e* from 0 to 28, inclusive. The represented value of (*s*, *f*, *e*) is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • *f* / 10<sup>*e*</sup>.

Define the canonical representation of (*s*, *f*, *e*) to be (*s*, *f* • 10<sup>*n*</sup>, *e*+*n*) for the greatest integer *n* for which *f* • 10<sup>*n*</sup> < 2<sup>96</sup> and *e* ≤ 28. If *e* is not 28, the canonical significand is in ceiling(2<sup>96</sup>/10), 2<sup>96</sup>−1, inclusive.

We can iterate through the non-negative `decimal` values in ascending order by:

```
    Set s = 0, e = 28.
    For f from 0 to 2^96 - 1, inclusive:
        Process (s, f, e) as a decimal value.
    For e from 27 down to 0, inclusive:
        For f from ceiling(2^96 / 10) to 2^96 - 1, inclusive:
            Process (s, f, e) as a decimal value.
```

We can see this is ascending order since each loop on `f` starts with a greater represented value than the previous loop ended with. We can see each representable value is included because the value for any canonical representation (*s*, *f*, *e*) appears in the loop on `f` where `e` has the value *e*. We can see no value is duplicated because each representable value is processed just once, in its canonical representation.

To restrict this to particular lower and upper bounds *L* and *U*, we can find the canonical representations of *L* and *U*. The components of these representations tells us where to start and end `f` and `e`. An alternative form of the algorithm may be more suitable for this. Let `fL` and `eL` be the *e* and *f* of the canonical representation of *L*, and similarly for `fU` and `eU`. Then an algorithm is:

```
    (0) Set s to 0, f to fL, and e to eL.
    (1) If e ≤ eU and f > fU, stop.
    (2) Process (s, f, e) as a decimal number.
    (3) Set f to f+1.
    (4) If f is less than 2^96, go to (1).
    (5) Set e to e-1 and f to f/10.
    (6) Go to (1).
```

The extension to negative numbers is obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'll test it out, but a first "think it through" looks very promising! Would upvote multiple times if possible :)