# incorrect double to integer convertion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am realy sorry to ask so simple question, but I realy can't figure out what is the problem.
I want to convert any mark to 12 grade scale. I am trying to this as following:

```
double coef=(4/20)*12;
int mark=(int)coef;
```

But when i execute this code via debugger I see that `coef` is equal to zero. Why if this is double variable?

Comment: What is the value of `coef`? What is value of `(4/20)*12`? What is the value of `(4/20)`? (Hint: its a hint)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I divide two integers to get a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/661028/299327)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because even though you're *assigning* the result to a `double` value the *calculation* is performed using integers. And `4 / 20` in integer arithmetic in C# is `0`. So you need something like

```
double coef = 4.0 / 20 * 12;
```

The `4.0` ensures that the rest of the calculation uses `double`s. But often it's actually a good habit to make all your numbers explicit so that readers don't have to know about type conversion rules:

```
double coef = 4.0 / 20.0 * 12.0;
```

Comment: @seeker If this solved your problem, then you should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's integer division until it needs to be converted...

```
4/20 = 0
0 * 12 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to do:

```
4 * 12 / 20;
```

But be aware that the result will truncate to 2 (because this is still integer division), which is okay, because that's what your cast to `int` would have done anyway.

Also, be aware that casting to `int` will truncate, not round. Use `Math.Round` if you want to actually round the result. It makes no difference with the numbers you gave, but I assume you'll not actually going to be only working with these constants!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing integer division first, then multiplying by 12.

When you do:

```
(4/20)
```

That's evaluating to 0, because they're both integers.

Modify it so explicitly state doubles by:

```
double coef = (4.0 / 20.0) * 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
double coef = (4.0/20.0)*12;
```

then

```
int mark = (int)coef;
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the constants in the code are integers, and the result of 4/20, as an integer, is 0.

You'll want to rewrite it as:

```
(4.0/20.0)*12.0;
```