# Divide in C# with incorrect result

Tags: c#

I have problem with some divide constructs in C#.
When i try to divide 2 numbers i always get result of zero what is incorrect result.

I have code like this.

```
double a = 100 / 1500;
```

I get result of `a=0;`
If i use

```
double a = 100d / 1500d;
```

I got correct result.
Where is problem in case 1 ? Can someone explain to me difference ?

Comment: It's doing integer division. Cast to double: `(double)100/1500`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/661028/56778

Comment: Integer division always truncates.

Comment: FWIW `double a = 100 / 1500d;` also avoids integer division; only the denominator needs the double suffix (d).