# I can't get the double result in my code

Tags: c#, math

In my code I can't get the right division I don't know why

I have for example ;

```
int N =5;
int df = 2;
double value = N/df;
```

when I use the previous code I get the value = 2 ,
I need return 2.5

Comment: Both values are int. Convert one of them value to double.

Comment: As AVD said: `double value = (double)N/df;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double

Comment: Yeah, the conversion happens AFTER the integer division, when you already lost the decimal part.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert one of the arguments to double:

```
  int N = 5;
  int df = 2;
  double value = ((double)N)/df;
```

or you can initially declare N and/or df as Double

```
  double N = 5;
  double df = 2;
  double value = N/df;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does work since I explicitly declare N and df as double.
You have to add ".0" in expressions like this: 5.0 / 2.0 which could be ambiguous
(5 - integer, 5.0 - double)

Comment: Sorry Dimitry, it does work. I had something else in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

An int  divided another int gives you an int.
One of the two should be a double.
This will work:

```
double N =5.0;
double df = 2.0;
double value = N/df;
```

This will work:

```
double N =5;
int df = 2;
double value = N/df;
```

Comment: @JeffRSon, you are right. I had something else in my mind. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add any double value to calculations

```
double N =5;
double df = 2;
double value = N*1.0/df;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this......

int N =5;
int df = 2;
double value = (double) N/df;
```

Comment: While answer works, please try to provide an explanation along with it.