# Dividing a decoded value, not minus/removing the last digit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net-3.5, decode

I have a method where I decode some information from a file, when I attempt to divide the value decoded by 10, let's say, it removes the last digit.

```
private int DecodeInt(byte[] bytes, int start)
{
    int r2 = 0;
    byte ch1 = bytes[start];
    byte ch2 = bytes[start + 1];
    int result = ch2 + (ch1 * 256);

    if (result > 32767)
    {
        r2 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        r2 = result;
    }

    return r2;
}
```

I know the value displayed should be 39.5.

```
Label_1.Text = (DecodeInt(Rec, 22)).ToString(); // Displays 395
Label_1.Text = (DecodeInt(Rec, 22) / 10).ToString(); // Displays 39
```

I'm confused as to why it doesn't function... I'm sure it will be simple adjustment but it's driving me a little mad.

Comment: You have to perform the conversion to the right numeric type (e.g., double), to be able to account for decimals.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing an int with an int so result will be in int only. What you can do is :

```
 Label_1.Text = (DecodeInt(Rec, 22) / 10.0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked here for my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/661042/2952390

```
double result = (double)DecodeInt(Rec,20)/(double)10;
```

Much easier than I thought, of course.