# Calculation is not working in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate a percentage for first pass yield but divide is not working and is returning a zero

```
double FirstPassYield = ((RowTotal - DefectCount) / RowTotal) * 100;
```

I tried individual calculations and they work except when I use divide. I even took to random numbers and divided them and still get a 0. I an not sure way divide keeps returning a 0

Comment: Are any of the variables of type `int` by any chance? Try using the search. "Calculation not working" is not a proper problem description and isn't going to yield any results, try "division returns zero".

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
double FirstPassYield = ((RowTotal - DefectCount) / (double)RowTotal) * 100;
```

When you divide `int` by `int`, the result is an `int` before being cast to a `double`, so you get zero instead of the value you are expecting.  By casting the denominator to a `double`, the rest of the calculation is cast to match, so you're working with `double`s instead of `int`s *before* the assign.

Comment: that works but how do I get my value to output like this 95.20%? I use toString("P") but how to move the decimal? My current output is 9520.55

Comment: Don't multiply by 100.  A percentage in C# is on a scale of 0 - 1, not 0 - 100.