# Confusing stuff on dividing two integers

Tags: c#, int

Hi everyone today I was testing some stuff and find an issue.

See:

```
int a = 13;    
int b = 10;
double c = a/b;
```

The result is **`1`**. or should it be like this ?

Comment: change int to double

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I divide two integers to get a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double)

Answer (score 1):

Dividing an `int` by `int` performs integer division. If you want to perform decimal division, cast one of the operands to `double`.

```
double c = (double)a / b;

// ---OR---

double c = a / (double)b;
```

Also, declaring `c` as `double` does not guarantee decimal division. It can be an implicitly typed variable too. As long as one or both of the operands of the `/` operator is of type `double` (or `float`, `decimal`, etc.) you will get a decimal result.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify that you want a `double` precision, for example

```
int a = 13;
int b = 10;
double c = a/(double)b;
```