# Decimal value after calculation

Tags: c#

I can't understand what is wrong? I have a little variable.

`decimal Price = 22348 / 100;`

The answer I get is: 223, but I should get 223.48. What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I divide two integers to get a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are doing is this:

```
decimal = (decimal)(int / int);
```

So you are calculating integers (yielding the result you get) and then convert the outcome to a decimal.

Instead, you could cast either of the operands to a decimal:

```
decimal Price = 22348 / 100M;
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but what does the "M" do after the 100?

Comment: Cool. Learn something new each day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare those numbers as decimal variable then put the divisions result in the other decimal variable.

```
    decimal num1 = 22348;
    decimal num2 = 100;
    decimal Price = (num1 / num2);
    Console.WriteLine(Price);
```

This will give the result `223.48`