# Set value for Progress bar in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I have value of a field coming from server lfrom 1 to 100 which is to show progress of that field. But I checked that we can provide value to progress bar from 0 to1. How can i convert this. I did something like this but didn't work

```cs
Int Field = 12; 
Decimal d = Field / 100; 
Decimal dc = Math.Round(d,1); //to round to one decimal place 
return dc;
```

This is returning 0.
I tried this too:

```
double d = (double)(Progress / 100);
double dc = Math.Round(d, 1); 
return dc;
```

This is also returning 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want maximum precision, you can convert an old range of values in a new range maintaining the ratio with this formula:

```cs
var OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin);  
var NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin);  
//i'm using round here has you requested, but its better to dont use it to achieve best results
var NewValue = Math.Round(((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin, 1);
```

In your case, taking for example the number 12, this will be:

```cs
var OldRange = 99 //(100 - 1);  
var NewRange = 1 //(1 - 0);  
var NewValue = Math.Round(((12 - 1) * NewRange) / OldRange) + 0, 1);
```

Concluding the number 12 in the old range is 0.1 in the new range.

Or if you dont care that the old range starts from 1 and the new from 0, you can just divide by 100 and round the value:

```cs
Int field = 12; 
Decimal d = field / 100; 
Decimal dc = Math.Round(d,1); //to round to one decimal place 
return dc;
```

> Please note that in c# the divide operator is **/** and not % (wich is the modulus)

Comment: I am  debugging the last one, but the value of d and dc is coming 0

Answer (score 1):

> Turns out "/" operator doesn't work in C#

NO, **"/" operator do work in C#.**

You get a zero because `Field / 100;` is `int/int`, the result is 0;

`Progress / 100`  is the same, `int/int` get 0;

To make your code work. You can define the field as type `Decimal`  :

```
    Decimal Field = 12;
    Decimal d = Field / 100;
    Decimal dc = Math.Round(d, 1);
```

Or cast the `100` to `Decimal`:

```
   int Field = 12;
   Decimal d = Field /(Decimal)100;
   Decimal dc = Math.Round(d, 1);
```

You can see detailed answer in these two threads: [why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)

and

[how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double)