# Why does a double display as an int in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#

I would think this would be an oft-asked question, but could not find its duplicate. Googling didn't help, either.

Why does a double display as an int in the visual studio debugger, as shown below:

[image]

The value should be around 4.4 or so. Why does Visual Studio just show a rounded version of the value? More importantly, how can I get it to show a real value rather than an approximation?

Comment: Because of integer division. One int divided by another will always give you an int result. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it. Can you clarify which variable you're asking about, and also show the code that assigns a value to that variable, as well as the types of all the variables and expressions and properties involved. As @itsme86 says, it might be because of integer types being involved, but your breakpoint is on a line assigning a value to `iWordsInDoc2`, and your highlighted watch is on a value of the variable `iCountOfLettersInDoc2`. There is no way to answer your question unless you clarify **what** you're asking about.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: The values in the Watch window tell the story, I think. Simple deal, I just forgot about it (been away from programming for years, and am working on a personal "hobby" project).

Comment: Unless I see your code declaring `iCountOfLettersInDock2` as a double, then I am inclined to believe you're just mistaken. I'm also questioning your claim that "count of letters in document 2" is 4.4. How can you have 4.4 letters in a document?

Comment: Or have you shown code with a breakpoint on X, highlighting a value on Y, and actually asking about Z? Aka, you have a breakpoint on assigning to `iWordsInDoc2`, you have shown a watch highlighting `iCountOfLettersOInDoc2`, but you're actually asking about `LettersPerWordInDoc2`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The "i" vars are integers, but WordsPerSentenceInDoc2  and LettersPerWordInDoc2  are doubles. The 4.4 letters are an average, as are the words per sentence.

Comment: Well, then see the current answer. Dividing an integer by another integer gives an integer result. Next time, also, be **clear** about what your code is portraying.

Comment: Please... Don't use Hungarian notation in c#. Obviously the choice is yours to make but it goes against most conventions. The name should indicate the purpose of the variable, not its type. If you ever have to change the type, now you've got to litter your diffs with (ie) `iSomething`->`dSomething` instead of just the declaration itself

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: I've always found that Hungarian helps me; I try to also make the names meaningful so what it is and what it is for are clear (to me, anyway). To some, Hungarian is just goulash, but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as the double in actuality holding an integer due to the fact that two integers divided against each other give an int result. To get the wanted double value, the ins must be cast to doubles like so:

```
double WordsPerSentenceInDoc2 = 0.0;
double LettersPerWordInDoc2 = 0.0;
. . .
WordsPerSentenceInDoc2 = (double)iWordsInDoc2 / (double)iCountOfSentencesInDoc2;
LettersPerWordInDoc2 = (double)iCountOfLettersInDoc2 / (double)iWordsInDoc2;
```

Comment: I think you only need to case one of them to double to get the proper division result.