# Percentage calculating returns 0 always

Tags: c#

My target is find percentage of 30 out of 45 which is `66.67%` but in following code it suppose to return `66.67%` however its returning 0. Whats wrong i am doing here?

```
public static void Main()
{
var percentage = 30 / 45 * 100; 
    Console.WriteLine("Percentage:" + percentage);
}
```

Comment: `var percentage = 30.0 /45.0 * 100.0;`, use `double` or `decimal`, not `int`.

Comment: 30/45 gives you 0 as int so use 30 / 45.0 * 100

Comment: Don't use `var` for primitive types like `int`, `double` and `string` or `bool`, please. Also you need to cast like: `double percentage = (double)30 / 45 * 100;` else you will get an integer result. Or use Dmitry's suggestion for literals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I divide two integers to get a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661028/how-can-i-divide-two-integers-to-get-a-double)